# Recent systemd startup and shutdown logs cleared

Tags: systemd, alma-linux

I'm on an AlmaLinux 8 server and recently applied patches. Five days after the patching process, I noticed that all recent systemd logs seem to be gone. These logs were present before but now I only have entries from 8 May and earlier are showing.

Here's what I've observed:

- Missing recent systemd logs: Logs from the past five days are absent which was present on the day of patching. No subsequent reboots was performed after server patching.
- Old systemd logs present: Entries from before 8 May are still available.
- Normal rotation for other logs: Logs like messages, mail, and secure are being rotated as expected.
- Default configuration: I haven't modified any rsyslog or log rotation configurations, and the system is using the default settings.
  Messages log: Systemd startup and shutdown messages appear to be logged here.

My questions:

- Could the recent patching have caused this issue?
- Is there a specific configuration needed to retain systemd startup and shutdown messages?

What steps can I take to troubleshoot the missing recent systemd logs?

- I've searched online and reviewed the default log rotation settings but haven't found a clear explanation for why recent systemd logs are missing while older ones and other logs are being rotated correctly. Any insights or suggestions would be greatly appreciated.